# ArrayControllerのarrangedObjectsが取得できません

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

このクラスはIBの方でTableViewのデリゲートをセットしてあって、TableViewの選択された行のデータを取ってくるつもりなんですが、ArrayControllerのarrangedObjectsが取得できません。

NSLogで@"Clicked: %ld"の方は正しく表示されますが、@"arrObj: %@"の方は(null)と表示されます。
変数_playListは、IBで生成したArrayControllerのOutletです。Core Dataのエンティティをセットしています。

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldSelectRow:(NSInteger)row{
        NSLog(@"Clicked: %ld", row);
        NSArray *tmp = [_playList arrangedObjects];

        NSLog(@"arrObj: %@",tmp);
        return YES; 
}
```

環境はOSX10.10.3 XCode6.3.1です。
よろしくお願いします。
もう訳わかんない。

Comment: 問題解決した。
ArrayControllerが正しく接続されていなかったらしい。
InterfaceBuilderでObjectを用意して、それにDocumentをセット。そのObjectからArrayControllerへ*playListを接続したらarrangedObjectsを取得できた。